# How do I supply either (1) dual voltage or (2) negative voltage?

Tags: power, voltage

Sorry in advance if this question already exists--I tried to search but my keyword knowledge is shaky. I have created a Colpitts oscillator on breadboard using AA batteries as the power supplies. I want to implement this oscillator with an Arduino. (Once it's set up, I want to use its voltage to do some things, but that isn't part of this question.)

In the image below, I have two voltages, Vcc (positive voltage) and Vee (negative voltage). My simulations indicate I can run the oscillator either with a dual voltage (+5V and -5V), or with one negative voltage (-5V) and the other set to ground. Either provides a 100 kHz oscillation from about -5 to 2 V. So:

- Is there a way to provide a dual voltage supply from the Arduino Uno?
- Is there a way to provide a single negative voltage supply from the Arduino Uno?

Thanks!

[image: Colpitts oscillator. According to simulations, I can set Vcc=0 and Vee=-5 and still observe oscillations]

Comment: No, but you could use a dedicated IC, for example http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm27762.pdf

Comment: After reading the post carefully, I'm confused why this is marked as off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

You can make -5 V if you use an external power source, like in the circuit below (untested).

Connect the GND (-) from the Arduino to the +5V from the External (5V) source, than 0V will be the GND (with respect to the Arduino), but the GND of the external source will be -5V with respect to the Arduino.

I only used the resistors to get no short circuits, you can replace it by your own circuit (connecting the 5V arrow to Vcc and the -5V arrow to Vee).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg7ZOB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>